# UIScrollView bounces back

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` embedded in a `UIView`. When scrolled down it bounces back to its viewable screen. I haven't got any clear fix on this.. I've looked at all the other questions.. no answer has been possible to my app.
This is my code...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    const CGFloat BoardWidth = 320;
    const CGFloat BoardHeight = 480;
    self.cScrollLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, BoardWidth, BoardHeight);
    self.cScrollLabel.contentSize = CGSizeMake(BoardWidth, 2 * BoardHeight);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I've disabled paging, enabled scrolling... What do I do?!?!?

Comment: Why are you calling viewDidLoad from viewDidAppear?

Comment: Should there be an error if I put it there?

Comment: yes.. put super viewDidAppear over there...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if it works.

to disable bounce use this -> scrollView.bounces = NO; to disable horizontal scrolling set content size of scrollview like this ->

```
float sizeOfContent = 0;
UIView *lLast = [scrollView.subviews lastObject];
NSInteger wd = lLast.frame.origin.y;
NSInteger ht = lLast.frame.size.height;

sizeOfContent = wd+ht;

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
```

Comment: have you taken through xib or coding?